# Brackets Shell URI

Tags: url, uri, adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

Does anyone know if Brackets Shell uses any URI except the `file://...index.html`  format? I want to point a web service back to the shell and need to provide a valid URI with the URL. The problem is that I noticed that the URL for the index file uses basic system paths and this can change per system or user configuration.

Any way around this little problem?

**Edit:**

I am trying to access the Instagram API through brackets shell. In order to gain an access token to the OAuth method they use I need to redirect the user to the Instagram Login page to log in then grant access and then Instagram will redirect them back to me based on the call back or redirect url provided from me. If it was as simple as providing just the URL when the call was made I would be fine however to get a client key (which is also needed to access the api) I need to provide the correct call back URL once the key is made and since the shell seems to have no custom file path it's almost impossible to predict the file path based on each users setup on their own pc's. I hope this made sense :)

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you're trying to do? Do you just need to set up a push connection from a web service back to brackets-shell? Is it really a web service that _only_ returns information if you make a frame navigate to it and then serves up a redirect back to some other server? It's not possible to just make a JSONP request or CORS request directly to the web server? (That sounds like a weird setup). Or are you looking for a custom URL handler that can _launch_ brackets-shell even when it wasn't already running?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the source of the [brackets-shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell), but couldn’t find the startup path. A quick workaround would be adding a [`meta-refresh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#For_redirection) to your `index.html` which redirects to the corresponding URL of your web service.

For example:
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com">`

If you don’t want to select your `index.html` each time you start your custom shell, you should place your `index.html` at

- Mac: Brackets.app/Contents/dev/src/index.html or Brackets.app/Contents/www/index.html
- Win: dev/src/index.html or www/index.html (these folders must be in the same folder as Brackets.exe)
- Linux: dev/src/index.html or www/index.html (these folders must be in the same folder as the Brackets executable)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, my problem though is that the web service needs to redirect back to the shell and for that to happen I need a valid URI and URL. If I have a meta-refresh in the index.html it won't actually help me much since I cant even reach the index.html with the callback from the server... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current location through javascript using

```
document.location.href
```

this will return a string like

```
"file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/YourApp/www/index.html"
```

which you might try sending to Instagram. I'm not sure if they will accept file URI's though.